# Cannot eject hdd from files tab even when forced through cmd

Tags: hard-drive, unmount, eject

Hi all Im very new to linux and have just bult my first linux based computer and having some issues with my internal storage hdds.

I have one 18tb seagate connected to my adeptec pcie card via sas, and for some reason I cannot seem to eject it from the file tab and for some reason it shows up as a disk drive(see screen shot).[image: hdd]

Every time I try to eject it I get the following error:

```
Error ejecting/dev/sda:Command-line'eject'/dev/sda" exited with non-zero exit status1: eject:unable to eject, last error: inappropriate ioctl for device:
```

[image: Error]

Its a brand new drive and just been formatted so unsure what is going on.

Ive tried to eject in command line but get the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only removable drives connected trough e.g. USB can be "ejected". After ejecting, they are not "seen" anymore by the OS, unless you plug them out then back in again.

This is different from an internal disk, like your disk attached through you card. These remain visible to the system. At most, you can disconnect, i.e., "unmount" the file system such that that is closed and not accessible. It is also normal that an additional internal volume, be it a different partition, or a partition on another drive, that is not announced in the configuration file `/etc/fstab`, is shown as a drive in the left panel of the file manager. That allows you to connect to it, i.e. mount it, by clicking the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your response it makes sense. much appreciated. Just finding my gears with Linux.

Comment: Sorry I upvoted it rather than ticking it as the answer. Thanks for the help,